# Haskell multiple if otherwise

Tags: haskell

Hello I'm trying to use imbricated conditions but I get parse error:

```
parse error on input ‘|’

isAssignMent::String->Bool
isAssignMent a
    | a == "" = False
    | otherwise
        | (head trimmed) == '=' = True
        | otherwise = False
        where 
            trimmed = trimRightSide a [' ', '\n']
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: `otherwise` is just a synonym for `True`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
isAssignMent::String->Bool
isAssignMent a
    | a == "" = False
    | (head trimmed) == '=' = True
    | otherwise = False
        where 
            trimmed = trimRightSide a [' ', '\n']
```

Guard clauses are checked sequentially. You only need an `otherwise` clause at the very end.

Answer (score 5):

You can also write this more idiomatically with pattern matching:

```
isAssignMent::String->Bool
isAssignMent ""         = False
isAssignMent a
    | '=':_ <- trimmed  = True
    | otherwise         = False
    where 
        trimmed = trimRightSide a [' ', '\n']
```